# How to zip a file in Ubuntu

Tags: zip

I use Ubuntu.
When I have to zip a folder I use the command `zip folder.zip folder/`

The result is an empty zipped folder!
Where did all the files in the folder go?

Comment: I used information from this question and answer in a script, but I guess that's not "programming" for some...

The simple, perhaps "noob", questions are often the most useful and time saving on this website. 

Documentation is often marginal. The best way to learn and find answers fast is generally FAQ/Q&A. A community driven Q&A assists a lot of people where documentation fails. Should we make a new, competing website, if this is not welcomed here?

Comment: I think you mostly miss a `*` by the end...  `zip folder.zip sourcefolder/*`

Comment: If you do this more than once, it might also be helpful to add `-x "*.zip*"` otherwise you inculde the "old" zipfile in your "new" zipfile

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install zip -y
zip -r folder.zip folder
```

The `-r` flag will tell it to be recursive, which may be needed for a directory.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install zip` first

Comment: In case you are just bundling fairly uncompressable stuff like jpg or mp3, you can opt for zero compression with `-0`, i.e. `zip -0 -r sample1.zip sample1/*`

Answer (score 10):

If zip command is not working then you need to install zip first. Here is the command which will install zip, gzip and tar.

```
sudo apt-get install zip gzip tar
```

then you can zip, gzip or tar.
zip the folder :

```
zip -r myzipped.zip my_folder
```

Here -r means recurrsive.

Here are some more related useful commands :

```
unzip myzipped.zip
tar -cvzf my.tar.gz directory_name
tar -xvzf myzipped.tar.gz
```

Comment: Regarding „some more useful“: creating a tar ('tape archive') and zip (aka creating the [pkware zip file format format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) most popular under windows) are [not at all the same thing](https://superuser.com/a/173825/75914).

Answer (score -1):

check out solution below:
You can create a simple zip file with zip command without using any options.

For example to create a zip file of text files first_file.txt, second_file.txt and third_file.txt run below command:

```
sudo zip newfile.zip first_file.txt second_file.txt third_file.txt
```

The output should be:

```
adding: first_file.txt
adding: second_file.txt
adding: third_file.txt
```

for more information [visit](https://linux4one.com/how-to-create-zip-files-in-linux/)

Comment: Why using sudo?

Answer (score -1):

To zip a folder in linux use below command

```
zip -r <OutputFile> <InputFile/FolderName>
```

For Example ( if static is a folder name)

```
zip -r static.zip static
```

Answer (score -2):

Let's take the question "How to zip a file in ubuntu" as "how to compress a file in Ubuntu".

Please note that you have the following trade-offs:

- Speed at compression time
- Speed at decompression time
- Size of archive
- Additional features (e.g. adding a password)

Also, you can distinguish creating an archive (multiple files in one file) and compressing it. If you see it as a two-step process ((1) Archive (2) compress) you can solve them independently.

Please also note that different compression algorithms shine in different scenarios. There is no single algorithm that is always best ("no free lunch")

## zip

- [`m̀an` page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip)

```
# A file
zip your_big_file

# Archive a directory + compress it
zip -r compressed.zip your_big_directory
```

## gzip

- [`man` page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip)

```
# -9: Use strongest (and slowest) compression
gzip -9 your_big_file
```

## tar

- [`man` page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar)

```
# Archive a directory + compress it
# c, --create         : Create a new archive.
# -z, --gzip, --gunzip: filter the archive through gzip
# -j, --bzip2         : filter the archive through bzip2
# -f, --file=ARCHIVE  : Use archive file (or device) ARCHIVE.
tar cvzf compressed.tar.gz your_big_directory/
```

## bzip2

- [`man` page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bzip2)

```
# -9: Use strongest (and slowest) compression
bzip -9 your_big_file
```